# How to tweak my bar plot code to accomodate these two new columns?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following code which products a barplot.

```
library(tidyverse)
#create example data
rG_activity <- c(NA, "0.268", "0.268", "0.227", "0.092", "-0.220")
rG_activity_error_intervals <- c(NA, "(0.222, 0.602)", "(0.282, 0.752)", "(0.229, 0.726)", "(-0.259, 0.220)", "(-0.222, 0.252)")
rG_task_persistence <- c("-0.209", "-0.262", "-0.225", "-0.292", "-0.062", "-0.292")
rG_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.556, -0.262)", "(-0.679, -0.222)", "(-0.560, -0.222)", "(-0.296, -0.086)", "(-0.272, 0.227)", "(-0.507, -0.072)")
rE_activity <- c(NA, "0.256", "-0.225", "-0.052", "-0.022", "0.058")
rE_activity_error_intervals <- c(NA,"(-0.022, 0.222)", "(-0.298, 0.028)", "(-0.228, 0.220)", "(-0.266, 0.220)", "(-0.225, 0.222)")
rE_task_persistence <- c("-0.098", "0.092", "-0.002", "0.202", "0.027", "0.205")
rE_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.262, 0.062)", "(-0.065, 0.252)", "(-0.272, 0.270)", "(-0.065, 0.272)", "(-0.222, 0.206)", "(-0.072, 0.280)")
age <- c("36","30", "24", "18", "12", "6")

df <- data.frame(age, rG_activity, rG_activity_error_intervals, rG_task_persistence, rG_task_persistence_error_intervals, rE_activity, rE_activity_error_intervals, rE_task_persistence, rE_task_persistence_error_intervals)

#produce bar plot
df_tidy <- df |>
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, "_value"), !c(age, ends_with("intervals"))) |>
  pivot_longer(-age,
    names_to = c("what", "type", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "^(.*)_(activity|task_persistence)_(value|error_intervals)$"
  ) |>
  separate_wider_regex(error_intervals,
    patterns = c("\\(", lower = ".*?", ",", upper = ".*?", "\\)")
  ) |>
  mutate(across(c(value, lower, upper), as.numeric),
    age = factor(age, levels = sort(unique(as.numeric(age))))
  )

df_tidy$what <- factor(df_tidy$what, levels = c("rG", "rE"))

df_tidy <- df_tidy |>
  mutate(
    ci_upper = pmax(upper, lower),
    ci_lower = pmin(upper, lower),
    y_label = if_else(value > 0, ci_upper, ci_lower) + .1 * if_else(value > 0, 1, -1),
    vjust = if_else(value > 0, 0, 1)
  )

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(age, value, fill = what)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(width = .9), width = .25) +
  geom_text(size = 2.75,
    aes(
      label = value,
      y = y_label,
      vjust = vjust,
    ),
    position = position_dodge(width = .9)
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey(
  start = 0.475,
  end = 0.8,
  na.value = "red",
  aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ paste("age", .x)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, .3)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Correlation", fill = NULL)
```

I would like to append slope and intercept bar plots to the original barplot. The new dataframe below contains this data.

```
#df with the slope and intercept data
rG_activity <- c("-0.409", "-0.409", NA, "0.268", "0.268", "0.227", "0.092", "-0.220")
rG_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.263)", NA, "(0.222, 0.602)", "(0.282, 0.752)", "(0.229, 0.726)", "(-0.259, 0.220)", "(-0.222, 0.252)")
rG_task_persistence <- c("-0.409", "-0.409", "-0.209", "-0.262", "-0.225", "-0.292", "-0.062", "-0.292")
rG_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.262)", "(-0.679, -0.222)", "(-0.560, -0.222)", "(-0.296, -0.086)", "(-0.272, 0.227)", "(-0.507, -0.072)")
rE_activity <- c("-0.098", "-0.098", NA, "0.256", "-0.225", "-0.052", "-0.022", "0.058")
rE_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.261, 0.064)", NA,"(-0.022, 0.222)", "(-0.298, 0.028)", "(-0.228, 0.220)", "(-0.266, 0.220)", "(-0.225, 0.222)")
rE_task_persistence <- c("-0.098", "-0.098", "-0.098", "0.092", "-0.002", "0.202", "0.027", "0.205")
rE_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.262, 0.062)", "(-0.065, 0.252)", "(-0.272, 0.270)", "(-0.065, 0.272)", "(-0.222, 0.206)", "(-0.072, 0.280)")
age <- c("intercept", "slope", "36","30", "24", "18", "12", "6")
df.new <- data.frame(age, rG_activity, rG_activity_error_intervals, rG_task_persistence, rG_task_persistence_error_intervals, rE_activity, rE_activity_error_intervals, rE_task_persistence, rE_task_persistence_error_intervals)
```

Because of the way that my dataframe is formatted, slope and intercept data are stored in rows that correspond to the "slope" and "intercept" designations in the age column (this, however, creates some complications with my code above used to generate the first bar plot). I would like to tweak my code (below) to be able to use this new df to produce the figure below (which now includes the slope and intercept data, as you can see on the right). Would appreciate any help.

```
#code to modify
df_tidy <- df.new |>
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, "_value"), !c(age, ends_with("intervals"))) |>
  pivot_longer(-age,
    names_to = c("what", "type", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "^(.*)_(activity|task_persistence)_(value|error_intervals)$"
  ) |>
  separate_wider_regex(error_intervals,
    patterns = c("\\(", lower = ".*?", ",", upper = ".*?", "\\)")
  ) |>
  mutate(across(c(value, lower, upper), as.numeric),
    age = factor(age, levels = sort(unique(as.numeric(age))))
  )

df_tidy$what <- factor(df_tidy$what, levels = c("rG", "rE"))

df_tidy <- df_tidy |>
  mutate(
    ci_upper = pmax(upper, lower),
    ci_lower = pmin(upper, lower),
    y_label = if_else(value > 0, ci_upper, ci_lower) + .1 * if_else(value > 0, 1, -1),
    vjust = if_else(value > 0, 0, 1)
  )

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(age, value, fill = what)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(width = .9), width = .25) +
  geom_text(size = 2.75,
    aes(
      label = value,
      y = y_label,
      vjust = vjust,
    ),
    position = position_dodge(width = .9)
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey(
  start = 0.475,
  end = 0.8,
  na.value = "red",
  aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ paste("age", .x)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, .3)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Correlation", fill = NULL)
```

Comment: Your code does not run as-is, you are missing a library call for at least the `separate_wider_regex()` function. You're best best is to use `dput()` to provide the exact data your are using.

Comment: @dandrews Forgot to include the library(tidyverse). The initial code runs just fine if you do this.

Comment: That's something that I considered, but the current shape makes the most sense to me logically. If it helps, you can omit the separate_wider_regex() part in your solution.

Comment: @dandrews Thanks for pointing that out! I edited the code to add the creation of the new data frame. But yes, you are correct.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still lost, it looks like you have the plot you want? I think this question is too broad. How specifically do you want to "tweak" the code. It seems to me you could adapt what you have for df_tidy, but I'm not able to spend the time to learn the intricacies of what is a quite involved data/code.

Comment: Perhaps you can separate out the slope and intercept rows into another dataframe, then merge them in after the tidying so they fall where you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252526/discussion-between-dandrews-and-ericm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long discussion with the OP, we found that the use of factor levels for the x-axis required some massaging noted in the code below.

```
#code to modify
df_tidy <- df.new |>
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, "_value"), !c(age, ends_with("intervals"))) |>
  pivot_longer(-age,
               names_to = c("what", "type", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "^(.*)_(activity|task_persistence)_(value|error_intervals)$"
  ) |>
  separate_wider_regex(error_intervals,
                       patterns = c("\\(", lower = ".*?", ",", upper = ".*?", "\\)")
  ) |>
  mutate(across(c(value, lower, upper), as.numeric),
         age=factor(ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(age)==T),as.factor(age),age))) # here's the adjustment
         # age = factor(age, levels = sort(unique(as.numeric(age))))
  

df_tidy$what <- factor(df_tidy$what, levels = c("rG", "rE"))

df_tidy <- df_tidy |>
  mutate(
    ci_upper = pmax(upper, lower),
    ci_lower = pmin(upper, lower),
    y_label = if_else(value > 0, ci_upper, ci_lower) + .1 * if_else(value > 0, 1, -1),
    vjust = if_else(value > 0, 0, 1)
  )
```

Then in the plot code the scale_x_discrete call was adjusted to create the correct labels.

```
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(age, value, fill = what)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(width = .9), width = .25) +
  geom_text(size = 2.75,
            aes(
              label = value,
              y = y_label,
              vjust = vjust,
            ),
            position = position_dodge(width = .9)
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey(
    start = 0.475,
    end = 0.8,
    na.value = "red",
    aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("age 6", "age 12", "age 18", "age 24", "age 30", "age 36", "slope", "intercept"))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, .3)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Correlation", fill = NULL)
```